# Android- Error Inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm working on a simple app that streams music and displays a Google map. When I try to put a map in the main activity, I get "error inflating class fragment".

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "activity started");

    gmap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1)).getMap();

    music = new MusicServiceWrapper(this);

}
```

and here is part of the layout file

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2" />
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error?

EDIT: I'll include some of the errors from LogCat (line 132 refers to the first line of the xml snippet I gave)

```
04-01 01:43:35.972: E/Trace(625): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-01 01:43:36.572: D/AndroidRuntime(625): Shutting down VM
04-01 01:43:36.572: W/dalvikvm(625): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.kenpowers.gea/net.kenpowers.gea.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #132: Error inflating class fragment
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #132: Error inflating class fragment
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-01 01:43:36.582: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
```

Comment: Could You share exact exception stack from LogCat?

Comment: I added the first 20 or so lines from LogCat. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

And also make sure that the Activity that is using the fragment(s) extends FragmentActivity instead of the regular Activity,

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

to get the FragmentActivity class.

I think your fragment XML file should be like this

```
<fragment
class="google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:id="@+id/fragment1"
android:name="com.yourapp.frag"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2" />
```

Have you added a Maps API key in your manifest?

Comment: My main activity was extending FragmentActivity, but I hadn't imported Fragment. Added that import to my code, but I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: what is the version of api...?

Comment: min android sdk is 14, target is 17

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
In XML,

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
 />
```

In Java

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity{

GoogleMap gmap;  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "activity started");

gmap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1)).getMap();

   }
}
```